# OnItemClickListener null view

Tags: android, list, view

I have a problem with OnItemClickListener.
I have a custom layout of a row in a listView that is implemented in rigaprodotto_new, inside there are AutoCompleteTextView and text boxes, as I use the other completer me it works properly and gives me the results to be chosen according to the text inserted by a dropdownlist, but when you press on one of them, in theory, I should complete the other car, but instead I am not able to associate the controller to the view of the line. Here's the code, thanks in advance ..

```
private OnItemClickListener codListener = new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        //View convertView = LayoutInflater.from(view.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.rigaprodotto_old, parent, false);
        View v = view;
        if ( v == null ) 
        {
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rigaprodotto_new, null);
        }
        // THIS RETURN NULL!!!
        AutoCompleteTextView codCompleter = (AutoCompleteTextView) (v.findViewById(R.id.autoCompleterOrdineArticoloCod));
        codCompleter.setText(""
                + codCursor.getString(codCursor
                        .getColumnIndex(OSDBManager.PRODOTTI_COD)));
        setProdotto((Prodotto) Controller.getElement(Controller.PRODOTTI,id, 0, 0),v);
    }
};
```

---

```
public void aggiungiRigaProdotto(View view,ProdottoOrdine p) {


    inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rigaprodotto_old, null);

    AutoCompleteTextView codCompleter = (AutoCompleteTextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.autoCompleterOrdineArticoloCod);
    .....
    codCompleter.setOnItemClickListener(codListener);
    codCompleter.setThreshold(1);
```

....

***EDIT*** 
ok works with the help of ADR, but there is another problem ...
codCompleter puts me in cursor @ 40b5c9d0 as text, but if I do see the value of codCursor.getString (codCursor
                     . getColumnIndex (OSDBManager.PRODOTTI_COD)) is right and is the string "cfg"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this it might help you.

```
 private OnItemClickListener codListener = new OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rigaprodotto_new, null);

    AutoCompleteTextView codCompleter = (AutoCompleteTextView) (v.findViewById(R.id.autoCompleterOrdineArticoloCod));
    codCompleter.setText(""
            + codCursor.getString(codCursor
                    .getColumnIndex(OSDBManager.PRODOTTI_COD)));
    setProdotto((Prodotto) Controller.getElement(Controller.PRODOTTI,id, 0, 0),v);
  }
};
```

Comment: it works ok but if you recall some control in that view and set the text, then do not enter anything!